# Matlab-reading large netcdf files

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I have a 17G netcdf file that I am trying to use for analysis.  Each variable in the netcdf file is set up like: variable(x,y,z,time).  I would like to read in and analyze the variables one 'time' at a time for analysis in Matlab.  In other words, I want to use all x, y, and z points at one time.  In the past I have had smaller files so reading in a variable has been set up like

```
fid=netcdf.open('filename/location','NC_NOWRITE');
var_id=netcdf.inqVarID(fid,'varname');
var=netcdf.getVar(fid,var_id);
```

Is it possible to read in the variables using one time step when the variable is read in?  (Incorrect syntax) It'd essentially look like

```
var=netcdf.getVar(fid,var_id,[:,:,:,time_index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the matlab netcdf command supports this, almost the way you wrote it:

```
data = netcdf.getVar(fid,var_id,var_index,var_length)
```

See the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/netcdf.getvar.html) for more information. You can also use [high-level matlab commands](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/network-common-data-form.html) instead of the netCDF library functions.
For example, if `varname` is a 100x4 array, you could get row 7 by using:

```
% read 4 columns from 1 row of data starting at row 7, column 1
v = ncread('filename/location','varname',[7 1],[1 4]);
```

or a four-dimensional array, as in the question:

```
% read all data from dim. 1-3 at dim 4 = 27
v = ncread('filename/location','varname',[1 1 1 27],[Inf Inf Inf 1]);
```

Comment: Since I have a four-dimensional array, wouldn't I need to start the command like

    data=netcdf.getVar(fid,var_id,[1 1 1 time_index]...

I'm having trouble picking out what the count and stride should be in order to get all of the x,y,z data from that time.

Comment: I added some example code to the answer. Also the documentation for the matlab "high-level" commands explains this issue much better than the documentation for the "package" commands which you are using. See the new link in the answer.